# How to Update CPanel Via SSH

Tags: centos5

I am on a server running CentOS 5 with WHM WHM 11.36.2 (build 0). Is there a way to update Cpanel using SSH or should I use the package manager of WHM?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find script that update cpanel at `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/upcp`. 
It runs each package's update script as you selected options among Automatic Manual Updates Only Never Update.

Comment: Okay, and then I can just update the package using `/scripts/upcp --force`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this procedure for cpanel update...
login to your server via SSH and run the following command as root or sudo:

```
[root#~]/scripts/upcp
```